# WCf rest install problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I created a wcf Rest service using net framework 4 and IIS 6.  I use route table in global asa .
It's working fine in my computer . When I 
Install it in Qa the service is not working.

When requesting the service I receive 404 
error.

The problem is that ISAPI filter of IIS cannot map between the request and the code.

Created separate pool for IIS application.
Please advice.

Web config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Global.asa

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          RegisterRoutes();

        }

        private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            WebServiceHostFactory factory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Data", factory, typeof(DataHandler)));
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("UserData", factory, typeof(UserData)));
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SetupData", factory, typeof(SetupData)));

        }
```

Comment: I do not have svc file . Therefore I set route table it's not a code problem. It's working in my compuer but not working in Qa

Comment: Then show us the `global.asa` file as well!

Comment: Can you please let us know what URLs you are using to access the site (in development and on your server), and whether you have installed under "Default Web Site" or an alias in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use routing with IIS 6, there's some special considerations that need to be made for routing. [Here is an article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) that walks through them. If you haven't taken care of these things, you're going to get 404s when you try to use your routes.

Comment: I already read the article . Choose firts option and it does not help. Furthermore I did not do anything in my computer with IIS 6 and it's worked.